Why isn't abortion premeditated murder?
If a person has been drinking and has a accident in a car and the passenger is 4 months pregnant and loses her unborn child, that's  involuntary manslaughter.
So how come when a healthy 4 month pregnant woman goes to a doctor who assists in planning and killing and disposing of the unborn child, that isn't premeditated murder?

canada
See Criminal Code, s. 223

A child becomes a human being within the meaning of this Act when it has completely proceeded, in a living state, from the body of its mother, whether or not (a) it has breathed; (b) it has an independent circulation; or (c) the navel string is severed.
A person commits homicide when he causes injury to a child before or during its birth as a result of which the child dies after becoming a human being

For the act to be homicide of the child, the child needs to exist in a living state outside of the body of its mother. The act that is considered homicide can occur before the child leaves the mother's body, though.
If the child does not ever exist alive outside the body of the mother, it is not a homicide of the child. See discussion in R. v. Drummond (1996), 112 C.C.C. (3d) 481, paras. 39-50 (Ont. Prov. Div.) (beware: disturbing facts).

england-and-wales
Because the law says so.
Firstly, killing an unborn child can never be murder. Murder requires killing a "person in being" which the courts have ruled does not include unborn children. Instead, if you deliberately kill an unborn child without a lawful excuse then you commit a separate offence of "child destruction" under Section 1(1) of the Infant Life (Preservation) Act 1929:

Subject as hereinafter in this subsection provided, any person who,
with intent to destroy the life of a child capable of being born
alive, by any wilful act causes a child to die before it has an
existence independent of its mother, shall be guilty of felony, to
wit, of child destruction [...]

Secondly, the law provides an exception for abortion, under Section 5(1) of the Abortion Act 1967:

No offence under the Infant Life (Preservation) Act 1929 shall be
committed by a registered medical practitioner who terminates a
pregnancy in accordance with the provisions of this Act.


So help me understand.   can you give me your legal definition of a few words..1. child 2 destroy 3 person..4 kill.

@TroyL The Act doesn't define any of those words. That's quite normal. Where a word is not defined in legislation, the courts will interpret its meaning according to various principles e.g. their ordinary dictionary meaning, the context, the drafter's intent, etc. In this case it's clear from the context that "child" here refers to a fetus (this is implied from the phrase "capable of being born alive"), "destroy" refers to causing the fetus to die, "kill" doesn't appear in the text, and I'm not sure what is unclear about "person".

"if you deliberately kill an unborn child without a lawful excuse..." What's an example of a "lawful excuse"?  (Or lack thereof)

@MichaelHall Abortion is one (see the second half of my answer). Another can be found in the second half of s. 1(1) of the Infant Life (Preservation Act) (which I didn't quote in full in the answer): "[an] act which caused the death of the child [done] in good faith for the purpose only of preserving the life of the mother". Others include self defence, soldiers at war, etc.

So would it suffice to say that an unlawful killing would only be one that was done against the wishes of the mother?

@MichaelHall That doesn't sound right to me. For example an abortion not performed by a doctor in accordance with the Abortion Act would be unlawful even if it was done in line with the mother's wishes. Same for the general case of child destruction where the purpose isn't to preserve the mother's life.

Interesting... I agree with that interpretation, but it seems to allow a corollary:  That a doctor could perform an abortion against the mother's wishes and it not be an offense per section 5(1).  Do you read it that way?  Where is consent addressed?  (is there a link to view the entire document?)
